# Downloading pdf file and open

Tags: windows-phone-7

In my application there is an option for downloading PDF. When the user clicks on the download button a file should be downloaded. After downloading is completed the user have an option to open the file. If the device contain a PDF reader then file should open else pop up a message containing *No PDF reader*. Also I want a progress bar showing the download status. If anyone knows the solution please help me.

Answer (score 2):

The best I've come up with is to use an embedded WebBrowser control - if you point the WebBrowser to the URL of the PDF, then it will get downloaded and the user will be prompted to open it in the PDF viewer.

The Windows Phone sandbox security model prevents file sharing between apps, except for very limited scenarios (pictures. music, ...)

Comment: I dont think pointing to the URL of the pdf will help anything. I tried and it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to display the pdf form web try this

just download and install  [ComponentOne’s WP7 Controls](http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/StudioWindowsPhone/)

and add this code to your xaml

```
<Grid>
        <c1Pdf:C1PdfViewer x:Name="pdfViewer"
                           ViewMode="FitWidth"
                           Visibility="Collapsed" />
</Grid>
```

in C#

```
 private WebClient wc = new WebClient(); 
private void MainPageLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) { 
    wc.OpenReadCompleted += WcOpenReadCompleted; 
    wc.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(http://some-url to point pdf)); 
} 
void WcOpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e) { 
    pdfViewer.LoadDocument(e.Result); 
    pdfViewer.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; 
}
```

this should display pdf from web , works fine for me :)

hope this will helps you for more reference see [this](http://nicksnettravels.builttoroam.com/post/2011/05/14/Display-PDFs-in-your-Windows-Phone-7-application.aspx)